# modificar configuración de una libreria con ajax

Tags: php, jquery

espero puedan responder mi pregunta y tratare de ser lo mas especifico posible

estoy utilizando una librería llamada "timepicker" el cual tiene su configuración en javascript en el cual puedes poner configuración de que hora a que hora puedes elegir

mi problema es que en mi formulario tengo un campo que al elegir una de las opciones , se supone que las horas  a elegir cambien,  pero esa configuración esta en javascript, y no se como modificar una configuración de una libreria sin recargar la pagina, cabe destacar que las horas las traigo en una base de datos

¿alguna idea?

anexo codigo donde quiero hacer todo

```
 <select id="field8" name="campus" aria-required="true" class="form-control 
  ui-button valid"> 
  <!-- aqui saldria el listado de elementos, no sale aqui porque esto sale por medio de ajax  -->                                                           
 </select>

<!-- donde quiero que me muestre las horas dinamicas -->
<div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-4" id="calendario"> <input id="field12" 
name="singleLineText2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="HORA" 
required>

<script>
$("#field8").change(function(){
var rutaHorarios ="get_horarios.php"; //enlace para hacer la consulta
horarios=ajaxStringSn(rutaHorarios,datoscampus); //funcion de ajax que me devuelve los horarios dinamicos dependiendo del la eleccion del listado
alert(horarios); //aqui pongo un alert para ver que me regresa
)}


$('#field12').pickatime({
min: [8,0],
max: [19,0],
clear: '',
disable: [
true,
<!-- AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO PONER LA VARIABLE DE HORARIOS YA QUE ME REGRESA LA 
CONFIGURACIÓN DE HORAS A ELEGIR EN LA BD
]
})
</script>
```

saludos

Comment: Podrías mostrar el formulario y el código js que tienes ?

Comment: listo edite la pregunta  y ya puedes ver mas explicitamente que quiero hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente, con este ejemplo lo que puedes hacer es definir que horas no se pueden seleccionar:

```js
//horas en las que NO esta disponible seleccionar
var disabledHours = [['13:00','13:01'],['8:00','8:01']];

//al cargar la pagina agrega estas horas sin excepciones
$('#durationExample').timepicker({
  'minTime': '2:00pm',
  'maxTime': '11:30pm',
  'showDuration': false,
});

//controlador que llama a cambiar las horas
function controlerHours(){
  changeHours(disabledHours);
};

//function para cambiar las horas teniendo como parametro las horas NO
//disponibles
function changeHours(disabledHours){
  //desactiva el timepicker para poder cambiar las horas
  $('#durationExample').timepicker('remove');
  
  //vuelve a cargar horas
  $('#durationExample').timepicker({
    'minTime': '8:00',
    'maxTime': '19:00',
    'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
    'showDuration': false,
    'disableTimeRanges': disabledHours
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/timepicker@1.11.12/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/timepicker@1.11.12/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" id="durationExample" />
<button onclick="controlerHours();">Cambiar horas</button>
```

espero sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: no es exactamente lo que necesito peeero, podria modificarlo e intentarlo gracias!!, te aviso como me fue

Comment: Eso es lo que se entiende con su pregunta, puede tratar de ser más especifico entonces

Comment: no osea si es mas o menos lo que quiero hacer, pero no de esa forma, pero puedo moficiar lo que yo entiendo y basarme en eso!

Comment: mmmm vale ya veo

Comment: solo una duda de esta parte        
   ` $('#durationExample').timepicker('remove');` 
esto tambien es para pickatime? ya que lo utilice ahi y no me funciono

Comment: esa linea lo que hace es quitar el timepiker de ese input, para poder cambiar las horas. Si trata de cambiar las horas sin removerlo antes, le genera un error

Comment: si pero es lo mismo poner $('#durationExample').timepicker('remove'); que $('#durationExample').pickatime('remove'); lo que me refiero es que si el remove es universal sin importar que libreria estoy utilizando?

Comment: .timepicker('remove'); esto esta en la documentación de esa librería : https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery debería de ser exclusivo de la librería

Comment: :(, sin ese remove en mi libreria no creo poder utilizarlo u_u

Comment: le da mucha vuelta al asunto, pero busque la libreria que mejor se adecue a su necesidad

Comment: muchas gracias!